# How to use WHERE clause on a field with comma seperated values in MS SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, where-clause

I have a table with a field with values stored in the "**STANDARD,ELITE,DELUXE**" format. I want to find all the rows where this field contains a defined value, e.g. **ELITE** or **ELITE,DELUXE**.

How can I perform a query in **MSSQL SERVER** to search a value in a field like this one?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: The *real* question is why are you storing delimited data in your database in the first place? Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: @Larnu Actually I don't want to make multiple entries for the same record just because of a single column. There can be more than 10-20 delimited values in a field. If I make different entries for each one of them, it won't be suitable. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there any other better way to achieve this task?

Comment: *"Please correct me if I am wrong."* You are. You are breaking the fundamental principles of normalisation. A value should represent one atomic value, and `STANDARD,ELITE,DELUXE` is 3 atomic values. You really need to normalise your design here. *That* is the real solution.

Comment: @Larnu thank you, I will make different entries. That would be simple and easy.

Comment: @FazilMir You could have a table that creates 1 row per value. I.e.:

ID.Value
1.DELUXE
1.ELITE

Add additional ID-columns as needed. I apologize about formatting. Not sure how to fix that in comments.

Comment: @SchmitzIT Thank you, I normalized it. It's working fine now.